# String and Cycle

Tags: c++

**Premise:** I'm a newbie on C and C++, that's why I need your help.

Hello guys, I have a problem with strings and cycle on C++ (I'm pretty inexperienced):

I want to make a simple login screen, I made a struct with username, password etc and I decided that the username must be >3 characters and <15 characters, but I don't know how to do it, let me explain:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    struct login{
        string userID;
        string userPSW;
        string userMAIL;
        char userGENDER;
    }login1;

        cout << "Username: ";
        cin >> login1.userID;
```

I made a an if/else, while and for, but when I try to compare a string with an int (like: **login1.userID < 15**), there is an error, I found some solution (like convert to int the string) but my code doesn't work.
So, can someone help me with this problem?

Another problem is while cycle, i tried with **char userID** , but the cycle keep spamming the **cout << "error"** that i made and it's not what i want, i want a cycle where there is an error if characters are **<3** and **>15** and cycle must return to **"Username: "**, with this method people can retry to insert an username.

I don't speak/write english very well, but I tried to get understood.
Thank you in advance guys.

STRING PROBLEM FIXED WITH YOUR HELP!
cycle problem still not solved :(

Comment: add your full code

Comment: *" i'm a newbie on C and C++"* - Lesson 1: C and C++ are different languages. What you write is C++, so don't double tag your questions.

Comment: Perhaps `userGENDER` should be an enumerated type

Comment: how do you try "to compare a string with an int" ?

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry

Comment: @pergy with atoi and stoi

Comment: 1.  Please ask **one** question per question.  2.  We need a [mcve] which shows your problem (rather than "my code doesn't work").

Comment: @Règik note, that will compare the content of your string, not the length

Comment: @EdHeal never do that, you'll end up with the LGBTDJZIDNRGHFJKKS consortiums bashing you!

Comment: STRING PROBLEM FIXED WITH YOUR HELP!
cycle problem still not solved :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare a `std::string` to a number. If you want to compare the length of the string, use `.length()`:

```
cout << "Username: ";
cin >> login1.userID;

if(login1.userID.length() > 15)
{
   cout << "please chose a shorter name." << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you nvoigt! it works! but with this method i can't retry to write username, the "please chose....name" pops up then it jumps out of "if" and i can't insert again my username. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Règik Well, you have no loop in your code. You should ask a new question and post your full code including a `while` loop as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare a `string` to an `int`. If you want to compare the string's length then you can use the `length()` method. It will return the number of chars in the string that you can compare.

Like

```
string barString = "hello"

if(barString.length() > 15)
    cout<< "string longer than 15 chars";
```